# AWS Lambda with java throwing NoClassDefFoundError caused by ClassNotFoundException which isn't thrown locally

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jar, aws-lambda, bazel

I've recently started playing around with AWS Lambda with Java.

It has been going well, until I started using Dagger 2 for injection.

Now Lambda throws the following error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "dagger/internal/Preconditions",
  "errorType": "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "com.company.server.user.SignUpActionAws.handler(SignUpActionAws.java:27)",
    "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)",
    "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)",
    "sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)",
    "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)"
  ],
  "cause": {
    "errorMessage": "dagger.internal.Preconditions",
    "errorType": "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException",
    "stackTrace": [
      "java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)",
      "java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)",
      "java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)",
      "com.company.server.user.SignUpActionAws.handler(SignUpActionAws.java:27)",
      "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)",
      "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)",
      "sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)",
      "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)"
    ]
  }
}
```

However, this does not occur when running `java -jar myjar.jar` locally. I've also checked that the class is in there using `jar tvf myjar.jar`.

I build using Bazel.

Other questions I've checked have suggested that it might be due to a dependency not being available, however, the contents of the class has no dependencies.

Taken from [the Dagger repo](https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/master/core/src/main/java/dagger/internal/Preconditions.java):

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2016 Google, Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package dagger.internal;

/**
 * An adaptation of Guava's {@code com.google.common.base.Preconditions} that is specially tailored
 * to support checks applied in Dagger's generated code.
 */
public final class Preconditions {
  /**
   * Ensures that an object reference passed as a parameter to the calling method is not null.
   *
   * @param reference an object reference
   * @return the non-null reference that was validated
   * @throws NullPointerException if {@code reference} is null
   */
  public static <T> T checkNotNull(T reference) {
    if (reference == null) {
      throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    return reference;
  }

  /**
   * Ensures that an object reference passed as a parameter to the calling method is not null.
   *
   * @param reference an object reference
   * @param errorMessage the exception message to use if the check fails
   * @return the non-null reference that was validated
   * @throws NullPointerException if {@code reference} is null
   */
  public static <T> T checkNotNull(T reference, String errorMessage) {
    if (reference == null) {
      throw new NullPointerException(errorMessage);
    }
    return reference;
  }

  private Preconditions() {}
}
```

What might be causing the issue on AWS that doesn't occur on my local environment when running a self-contained jar?

Thanks in advance

Edit 1:
Here is the minimal BUILD file:

```
java_binary(
  name = "bin",
  srcs = glob(["Action.java"]),
  main_class = "com.company.Action",
  deps = [
    "//external:aws-lambda",
    "//external:dagger",
  ]
)
```

Here is the WORKSPACE file:

```
bind(name = "aws-lambda", actual = "@com_amazonaws_aws_lambda_java_core//jar")
maven_jar(
  name = "com_amazonaws_aws_lambda_java_core",
  artifact = "com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-core:1.1.0"
)
bind(name = "dagger", actual = "@com_google_dagger//jar")
maven_jar(
  name = "com_google_dagger",
  artifact = "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.5",
)
```

Here is Action.java (note, I use Preconditions directly to make it the minimal implementation, in my actual code it fails when trying to build a component):

```
package com.company;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;

public class Action {
  public static void main(String[] s) {
    Action.handler(null, null);
  }

  public static String handler(String request, Context context) {
    dagger.internal.Preconditions.checkNotNull(new Object(), "Test");
    return null;
  }
}
```

If you run `bazel build //src/main/com/company:bin_deploy.jar` and upload it to an AWS Lambda function, it should fail. If you locally run `bazel run //src/main/com/company:bin` or `java -jar bazel-bin/src/main/com/company/bin_deploy.jar` it will work fine.

Comment: If you open up the jar in, say, WinZip (or list its contents with `unzip` on Linux) do you see the dependencies? Are they in the correct place?  If they are not supposed to be in the jar, do you have them deployed on the server in the correct place?

Comment: Yes, all of the classes are in there (including the Preconditions class). They are in the right location.
In terms of the server, that's where AWS Lambda comes in. I upload my full jar (containing all dependencies) to AWS Lambda and it takes it from there. Something to do with that seems to be causing issues.

Comment: Your build dependency might be incorrectly declared. What's your build file looks like?

Comment: @DamienMartin-guillerez I've edited my question to include the minimal files.

Comment: You might try an alternate build technique in an attempt to reduce your problem scope.  I'm not familiar with bazel, but I'm using the AWS Eclipse plug-in for all my Lambda work and find that it handles the build/packaging dependencies perfectly.  You might try building a basic package using the Eclipse plug-in and then cracking open the results to see if it leads you anywhere.

Comment: @Pete that's a good idea. Reducing the problem scope is always good. I'll give it a go asap. I might even try building it by hand.

Comment: So I tried logging the contents of directories inside of the jar (at runtime) to determine what was visible and what wasn't. It seems I can't access the root "dagger" folder, but I can access all of the other ones. I unzipped the jar to see the permissions, here is what i got://drwxr-xr-x META-INF//-rw-r--r-- build-data.properties//drwxr-xr-x  com//drwxr-x---  dagger//drwxr-xr-x  javax//drwxrwxr-x  models//drwxr-xr-x   mozilla//drwxr-xr-x   org//----So clearly the dagger folder has different permissions. But why? Anyone have any insights?

Answer (score 0):

It was all due to permissions in the dagger folder inside of my jar. All the other folders (e.g. com, org, mozilla) had 755, but not the dagger folder. I unzipped my jar, ran two commands to convert the directories to 755 and the files to 644, then I zipped it back up.

The commands for changing the permissions:

```
From inside the unzipped directory:
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} +
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +
```

I don't know why it is different to the other directories when Bazel is building it. But that is the problem.

---

For future Bazel searchers, here is the genrule I'm now using:

```
genrule(
  name = "target-aws",
  srcs = ["target_deploy.jar"],
  outs = ["target-aws.jar"],
  cmd = """
  unzip -q $< -d t
  cd t
  find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} +
  find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +
  zip ../$@ -q -r .
  rm -rf t
  """
)
```